# read from a text file and records are separated by empty lines (java)

Tags: java, class, file-io, io, arraylist

I am stuck with this problem, please help:
I want to read a txt file and put the content into an ArrayList, and the format is like this:

```
name                Yoshida Shuhei
birthday            8-04-1961
phone               0123456789
email               abc@123.com
medicalHistory      None
address             12 X Street, Suburb, 
                    NSW, Australia


address             13 Y Street, Suburb, VIC, Australia
name                Kazuo Hirai
medicalHistory      None
email               xyz@123.com
phone               0987654321
birthday            26-11-1972
```

the file contains several patient records, and the record within each patient’s records block may occur in any order(e.g. the first patient's *name* comes first, but the second patient's *address* comes first), and all records are separated by **blank lines**.

My idea is, if the current line is not a blank line, begin to read the patient records and add them into a patient object, here's my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Patient> getData(String fileName) {
        try {
                File file = new File(fileName);
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
                ArrayList<Patient> recordList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
                ArrayList<MedicalHistory> mhList = new ArrayList<MedicalHistory>();
                int index = -1;
                int mh_index = -1;
                String s;
                Patient p = null;
                MedicalHistory mh = null;
                boolean addressActive = false;
                boolean mhActive = false;

                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    s = reader.nextLine();
                    Scanner line = new Scanner(s);
                    String cmd;

                    if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        cmd = line.next();

                        if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                            index++;
                            p = new Patient();
                            p.setName(line.nextLine());
                            recordList.add(index, p);
                            addressActive = false;
                            mhActive = false;

                        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("address")) {
                            if (line.hasNext()) {
                                p.setAddress(line.nextLine().trim());
                                recordList.set(index, p);
                            }
                            addressActive = true;
                            mhActive = false;

                        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("birthday")) {
                            p.setBirthday(line.nextLine());
                            recordList.set(index, p);
                            addressActive = false;
                            mhActive = false;

                        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("email")) {
                            if (line.hasNext()) {
                                p.setEmail(line.nextLine());
                                recordList.set(index, p);
                            }
                            addressActive = false;
                            mhActive = false;

                        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("phone")) {
                            if (line.hasNextInt()) {
                                p.setPhone(line.nextInt());
                                recordList.set(index, p);
                            }
                            addressActive = false;
                            mhActive = false;

                        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("medicalHistory")) {
                            mh = new MedicalHistory();
                            //...parse the medicalHistory
                            addressActive = false;
                            mhActive = true;

                        } else if (addressActive) {
                            String address = p.getAddress() + " " + s.trim();
                            p.setAddress(address);
                            recordList.set(index, p);

                        } else if (mhActive) {
                            //to deal with multiple medical histories
                        } else
                            System.out.println("Error: no command:" + s);
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
                return recordList;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error:- " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
    }
```

The problem is, my code can only handle when the **name** comes first; if the first non-empty line begins with other command(e.g. begins with **address**), there will be no **new Patient()** initialized for it, and the program will get an error...

So where exactly should I put the **p = new Patient()** in, the program to read the patient records no matter what the order of commands is, and then store the data in a Patient object?

Can anybody be able to improve my code and satisfy this condition? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you read each block into a `HashMap<String,String>` that maps each attribute to its value from the file. When the block is finished (that is, when you see a blank line or the end of the file) you can process the block in whatever particular order of attributes you need so as to properly create a `Patient` object.

Alternatively, with your current logic, you only need to change it a bit to do what you want:

```
. . .
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    s = reader.nextLine();
    Scanner line = new Scanner(s);
    String cmd;

    if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        if (p == null) {
            // starting a new block -- create a new patient record
            p = new Patient();
            recordList.add(p);
        }

        if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            index++;
            p.setName(line.nextLine());
            addressActive = false;
            mhActive = false;
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("address")) {
            if (line.hasNext()) {
                p.setAddress(line.nextLine().trim());
            }
            addressActive = true;
            mhActive = false;

        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("birthday")) {
            p.setBirthday(line.nextLine());
            addressActive = mhActive = false;
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("email")) {
            if (line.hasNext()) {
                p.setEmail(line.nextLine());
            }
            addressActive = mhActive = false;
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("phone")) {
            if (line.hasNextInt()) {
                p.setPhone(line.nextInt());
            }
            addressActive = mhActive = false;
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("medicalHistory")) {
            mh = new MedicalHistory();
            //...parse the medicalHistory
            addressActive = false;
            mhActive = true;
        } else if (addressActive) {
            String address = p.getAddress() + " " + s.trim();
            p.setAddress(address);
        } else if (mhActive) {
            //to deal with multiple medical histories
        } else
            System.out.println("Error: no command:" + s);
        }
    } else {
        // blank line indicates end of block
        p = null;
    }
}
. . .
```

Note that when you modify the current patient record (referenced by `p`), you don't need to set the element of `recordList` again; it will be automatically updated, since it refers to the object already in the array list. With this, you don't need the `index` at all; you just add the new patient record to the end of `recordList` and keep modifying it as long as the input is still in the same block.

Comment: OMG, it works! you're a lifesaver! Thanks so much for your help. I've stuck on this problem for 2 days, and I just couldn't work this logic out...

Answer (score 1):

my idea would be to maintain the hashtable to store the complete data..

```
Hashtable<Integer,Hashtable<String,String>> ht = new Hashtable<Integer,Hashtable<String,String>>();
```

Integer to store the patient#, Hashtable to store the name,value pair.

`("address","<addr>"), ("name","<name>")`

HashMap is not thread safe.. It may give problem when you run it in multithreaded environment..

Comment: although I used another person's solution, Thanks for your help!